# divide a number by all values of column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

df1 have one column(total) with 2 values 5000 and 1000 each with id A & B respectively. df2 have one column(marks) with 10 values where first 5(100,200,300,400,500) values have id A and next 5 values have id B(10,20,30,40,50).
Now I have to get expected output as

```
   id    final_value 
 - A     50
 - A     25
 - A     16.6
 - A     12.5
 - A     10
 - B     100
 - B     50
 - B     33.3
 - B     25
 - B     20
```

my code is
`new_df = df1['total']/df2['marks']`

But I got output as

```
A    50
B    100
```

Remaining `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas division is using both "columns" (series), element by element.

If you want to divide using 'id' as a link, you have to merge your dataframes before :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[5000, 'A'], [1000, 'B']], columns=['test', 'id'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[100, 'A'], [200, 'A'], [300, 'A'], [400, 'A'], [500, 'A'], [10, 'B'], [20, 'B'], [30, 'B'], [40, 'B'], [50, 'B']],columns=['marks', 'id'])
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='id')
df3['test']/df3['marks']
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'total': [5000, 1000]}, index = ['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'marks': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}, index = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'])
```

Interestingly enough this works:

```
df2['total'] = df1['total']
df2['final_value'] = df2['total'] / df2['marks']
```

And then you can just drop the rows and copy answer to new df if you want it as you stated:

```
new_df = df2[['final_value']]
df2 = df2.drop(['total', 'final_value'], axis = 1)
```

Comment: I think the most interesting thing about the answers to this question is how the different answerers setup their dataframes!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=['A', 'B'], total=[5000,1000]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                    vals=[100,200,300,400,500,10,20,30,40,50]))
```

you can get the new column you're interested in by first merging the two dataframes on the `id` column and then applying a `lambda` function to divide the `total` by the value provided in df1. Specifically:

```
df2['final_result'] = df2.merge(df1, on='id').apply(lambda x: round(x.total/x.vals, 1), axis=1)
```

And if you only want the `id` and `final_result` columns, you can just select those:

```
df2[['id', 'final_result']]
```

Your data should now look like you expected:

```
    id  final_result
0   A   50.0
1   A   25.0
2   A   16.7
3   A   12.5
4   A   10.0
5   B   100.0
6   B   50.0
7   B   33.3
8   B   25.0
9   B   20.0
```

Note that in the lambda function I also applied some rounding to get just 1 decimal as you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
>>> df1.set_index("id").rename(columns={"total": "marks"}).div(df2.set_index("id")).round(1).reset_index()

  id  marks
0  A   50.0
1  A   25.0
2  A   16.7
3  A   12.5
4  A   10.0
5  B  100.0
6  B   50.0
7  B   33.3
8  B   25.0
9  B   20.0
```

It leverages the fact, that for any arithmetical operations between 2 data frames `pandas` will autofit both dataframe attributes by index, and columns (so the arithmetic operation will be index `x` on index `x` and column `a` on column `a`)